# How to update a database field by a value of 1 in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a simple system that counts the number of clicks on a given link.  I would like to increment the current number of clicks ($clicks) by 1. I tried something like $clicks++, but I guess it doesnt make sense. I am using wordpress and mysql, but I would prefer to do it using the ready update_field function than directly in the database. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
$clicks = get_field( "carousel-clicks", $post_id  );


update_field("carousel-clicks", $clicks++, $post_id);
```

Comment: Are you doing it in MySql.

Comment: Show your update_field function's code

Comment: where are you doint it ? the link exist where ? , save the counter values in post_meta and then use `update_post_meta()`

Comment: I am doing it via a new ACF field.

Comment: update_field is a ready Wordpress(or ACF) function therefore it is not relevant.

Comment: I don't understand. It should work perfectly the way you have it. `$clicks` should, and most likely is, numeric. You can increment it while passing it in the function as an argument. I can't see anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use increment in function parameter. You don't know what you get. You should change your code to:

```
$clicks = get_field( "carousel-clicks", $post_id  );
$clicks++;
update_field("carousel-clicks", $clicks, $post_id);
```

Comment: I would like to use the code that I have above - using the update_field function rather than directly working with database.

Comment: Ok I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was so easy:

$clicks = $clicks +1;